# Person whose recorded voice announces upcoming content on radio

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word/term for a person whose recorded voice on the radio announces the upcoming content, for example, musical piece, on radio?

I am not sure *host* or *narrator* would be quite correct, since they seem to imply more dynamic or extended engagement, respectively.

For example, the voice could say:

> And now, interview with Mr.X

And then the interview is carried out by a completely different person. Then the voice will say:

> Ludwig van Beethoven, piano sonata no.X

And the music will play.

Is there a specific term for this person's occupation?

Comment: I don't think *recorded* fits with the rest of the question: most announcers are employed specifically to speak live and link together recorded segments (though the entire programme may then be recorded for later transmission).

Comment: @TimLymington: I was thinking about a specific radio station which airs mostly classical music and I believe the voice is pre-recorded. I.e. it doesn't say "Beethoven, sonata 2" every time Beethoven's second sonata is aired.

Comment: That's an announcer.  Doesn't matter whether it's recorded or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would call them [*continuity announcers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Continuity_announcer)

Comment: They are not usually recorded, because part of their job is to cover in the case of unexpected events: "We apologize that due to technical difficulties we are unable to broadcast the scheduled episode of 'Jam Making Today'. Instead, here is some music."

Comment: Note that *continuity announcer* is British English. Very few people in the US would have any idea what a continuity announcer is (we would probably just say *radio announcer*).

Comment: Continuity announcer is sometimes used in the US, but mostly I think you'd just hear "announcer".

Comment: [The Guardian, 13 Nov 2012](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2012/nov/13/how-become-continuity-announcer): "Claire Gibb was a **continuity announcer** at Film4 before following her then boss to the BBC Public Domain..."

Answer (score 5):

First thing that came to mind was the simple "announcer".

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term *[emcee](https://www.google.com/search?q=emmcee&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=emcee&spell=1)*.  *Emcee* is the spelling of the abbreviation MC, which stands for "Master of Ceremonies", which is someone who "introduces speakers, players, or entertainers".

To be more exact, I would use a phrase like "emcee of the radio program", though just "emcee" would likely do.

Comment: Is "emcee" in current use for a radio host? The OED has a citation for that usage from the mid 1960s, whereas it has citations for "deejay" (what's with all the spelled-out letters?) from the 1950s to the 2000s.

Comment: Deejay stands for "Disc Jockey", which is a person who jockeys discs (CDs or records).  In other words, a DJ is someone who picks the music on the radio (or at a club, rave, etc.).  Since the implication of the question is that this is more about interviews and classical music, which is probably on a rotation or preset schedule, I would say that emcee is more appropriate.

Comment: The first British DJ Chrisopher Stone played classical records

Comment: I'm not saying you can't have a classical DJ. However, if the interviews and music are on a fixed schedule, then the term emcee is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @Nick2253 I agree that MC is more logical than DJ but the English language relates to logic like a fish relates to a bicycle and that's not my question. Is the term "MC/emcee" in common use for a radio host?

Comment: @DavidRicherby At least in my area, the people who "run" the music stations, like pop and classic rock, are called DJs, and the people who "run" the talk stations, like NPR, are considered emcees.

Comment: @Nick2253 OK -- thanks. Sounds like this might be a US/UK thing, then. I don't think I've heard them called emcees in the UK.

Comment: An "MC" or "emcee" is similar to a continuity announcer, but the term is employed only in the context of a live program. (for example, the "host" of an awards program is often called the "MC"). To the best of my knowledge, the term is not generally used in radio. (either in US or UK English)

Comment: @Nick2253 - what part of the world are you in that you get this usage?

Comment: @JonKiparsky US Pacific area. Oregon to be specific. In my neck of the woods, I'd say that emcee isn't exclusive to live events, and hear it regularly used for TV and other things.

Comment: Huh. I was an announcer on KBOO in Portland for years, but nobody ever called me an emcee...

Comment: I was an *announcer* on my college's classical station, and a *DJ* on my college's not-classical station. One of the classical announcers called himself a DJ once and that was definitely a "Dude, no" type of situation. No one ever called themselves an emcee--that's for real-life events.

Answer (score 1):

A [radio personality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_personality), radio host, radio announcer, or [radio DJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_jockey#Types) (or just "DJ" or "disk jockey").

Answer (score -1):

- Either an announcer or a narrator.